# IText edit or remove the layer on PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, layer, ocg

H All,

I am Using IText for adding text layers on PDF.
Now i want to edit the existing layers on the PDF, layers are also created by IText only. Seems IText dont have such methods to suppport.

I thought of other way around is remove existing Layer and place new layer on its place. Seems remove also not supported by IText. Any way todo these?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: PDF does not as such have a concept of layers. If you add something to a PDF in the background, you simply prepend it before the existing content; for the foreground, you append it thereafter. This been said, if you really only used iText to do such kind of changes, these change sets can be recognized and removed. It merely requires using the iText low level API.

Comment: Or do you refer to what iText calls a `PdfLayer` which actually is an optional content group in PDF lingo?

Comment: Yes i am talking about PdfLayer -- using this i will create a text and place it on PDF, we can see on PDF Viewer tools it as a layer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turned out in comments, the layers in question are what iText indeed calls layers but what actually in PDF lingo is called *optional content groups.*

There indeed is a utility class for removing such layers in the iText Xtra package (not the extrajars, but itext-xtra.jar): [`com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ocg.OCGRemover`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGRemover.java) which makes use of the class [`OCGParser`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGParser.java) in the same package.

```
/**
 * Class that knows how to remove OCG layers.
 */
public class OCGRemover
{
    /**
     * Removes layers from a PDF document
     * @param reader    a PdfReader containing a PDF document
     * @param layers    a sequence of names of OCG layers
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void removeLayers(PdfReader reader, String... layers) throws IOException
    [...]
}
```

After applying that method to a `PdfReader` you obviously have to save the changes, e.g. by means of a `PdfStamper.`

Comment: Yes i tried this but throwing exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytes(PdfReader.java:2281)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ocg.OCGParser.parse(OCGParser.java:132)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ocg.OCGRemover.parse(OCGRemover.java:222)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ocg.OCGRemover.removeLayers(OCGRemover.java:81

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF for reproducing the issue?

Comment: Ah, I just spotted one possible reason for the NPE: `OCGRemover.parse` uses `page.getAsStream(PdfName.CONTENTS)` to retrieve the page contents. But the contents do not need to be a single stream, they may also be an array of streams, and in that case `getAsStream` returns `null` which then is forwarded to `OCGParser.parse` to parse which then explodes in your face during `PdfReader.getStreamBytes.` Ok, so `OCGParser.parse` should be extended to also handle contents arrays... oh well, the xtras have a somewhat experimental character...

Comment: Might be you are true.. this xtra doesn't help me.

Comment: If you extend it to cope with arrays,  too,  it does help. If you supplied the PDF, the possible reason could be verified.

Comment: I think this was fixed either in the latest version or in the version that will be released next week (I remember encountering that problem myself and fixing it, but I don't remember when I fixed it).